# Rails Query returning nil! while SQL query returning response for the same query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In Rails Console i'm trying something like

```
College.where(course_id: 1, start_year: '2020-01-01')
```

IN SQL

```
select * from College where course_id = 1 and start_year = '2020-01-01' ;
```

This SQL query is returning the required response .

Comment: What does `College.where(course_id: 1, start_year: '2020-01-01').to_sql` return? (edit your question and add the output of that).

Comment: What is the table name?

Comment: Are you sure the column name is start_year & the value is not like a year (eg: 2020) but the date (eg: 2020-01-01)?

Comment: Rails uses plural table names. So unless you have set `self.table_name = "College"` in `models/college.rb` its pretty likely that you are reading from a different table in the database client then in the rails query. Run `College.where(course_id: 1, start_year: '2020-01-01').to_sql` and compare the queries. You can also actually see the sql query run by rails in the console.